# Mountain Lion drops internet when waking

Tags: macos, sleep-wake

Since updating to Mountain Lion I lose my internet connection every time that my 24 inch Mid 2007 awakens from sleep. It doesn't occur when going to sleep or during but only on activating it again. 100% of the time. Any ideas?

Comment: Please add what model of iMac this is. Have a look at the "System Information" app. Should be something like iMac7,2

Comment: It's a 24 inch Mid 2007 with 2.4 GHz Intel Core 2 Duo. The internet connection is WiFi.

Comment: From what I can see on the coverage for Mountain Lion 10.8.1 (there was a beta update seeded to developers, according to Engadget and others), there is a known issue with wi-fi which is being addressed by this update.

Comment: FWIW my Mac Pro as well has the same issue for wired network connections...

Answer (score 2):

I called Apple Tech Support yesterday. My connection drops after waking from sleep, and it is a hardwired connection (not wifi). They told me it is a known problem with iMacs, and while it eventually will be fixed in a software update, the only thing to do now is to disable the machine sleep on the energy saver panel, which I did..

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too. I solved it by going to my router's configuration settings and changing some settings under the WiFi setting (it worked for me).

First of all make sure you’re using WPA2; for WPA-type use passphrase and choose your password. But make sure there are no numbers in your network password.

Second change your channel. Before I had set it on channel 6 now I changed it on channel 11.

Also make sure your encryption is set to AES.

I'm giving you also a picture of my WiFi settings down below.
[image: settings]

Comment: "But make sure there are no numbers in your network password" - without evidence to the contrary, that's ridiculous.

Comment: Just try and you shall see! ;) posted this olso on another forums and for 90% of them it helped! is that also ridiculous...?

Comment: I assume that changing the channel contributed more to the solution than using a password not containing any digits.